# how should I change this to use CCParallaxNode?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, background-image, side-scroller

Hello I am a beginner to cocos2d and objective c. I am making a cocos2d side scroller. How can I make this code be continuous??

```
 backgroundNode = [CCParallaxNode node];
    [self addChild:backgroundNode z:-5];
    treeBackground = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"thechangedbackgroundcopy.png"];
    CGPoint backgroundSpeed = ccp(0.5, 0.5);
    [backgroundNode addChild:treeBackground z:-5 parallaxRatio:backgroundSpeed positionOffset:ccp(screenWidth/2, screenHeight/2 - 50)];

    [self scheduleUpdate];



-(void)update:(ccTime)delta{
CGPoint backgroundScrollVelocity = ccp(-150, 0);
backgroundNode.position = ccpAdd(backgroundNode.position, ccpMult(backgroundScrollVelocity, delta));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out great series of tutorials [on Ray Wenderlich site](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3611/how-to-make-a-space-shooter-iphone-game)

The part you ask about is covered in the **Adding Parallax Scrolling** paragraph.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I have edited my question at the top. How should I make this continuous?